# how to change the size of the figure in rmdformats/html_docco

Tags: r, html, r-markdown

Install the rmdformats package, and I'm using the html_docco template from [github](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats). How to change the size of an image that is on the internet.

```
---
title: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rmdformats::html_docco:
    highlight: kate
---
```

I'm trying to do the following, but it does not work.

```
![](http://blog.hackerearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/SQL-FQ.png){width=150%}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need speech marks on the proportionate size:

```
![](http://blog.hackerearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/SQL-FQ.png){width="150%"}
```

I hope this helps.